# Chrome Extension Run across all tabs/windows

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have found that using background: scripts does not allow for the extension to run across all existing windows and tabs or new windows and tabs. After some research I found a post relating to content-scripts. However I am having trouble getting this to work across the tabs/windows.

Is anyone able to assist me making this work across all tabs and windows and new tabs/windows.

If I open www.twitter.com I want it block the site using the script and tell me in the console that it's done that. I am also retrieving values from Xively which I want it to show in the console across any tabs that I open.

On a sidenote, How can I compare the current URL to a list of predefined URLS. If the value from Xively is "tag1" I want it to use a list of predefined sites and block them all. If it is "tag2" I would like It to block another set of predefined sites.

**EDITED1** to give a more comprehensive example of what I am trying to achieve.

**EDITED2** Using my code I have now managed to block websites by changing the tagger variable which stores the URLs, however I am not unable to unblock those sites when a different tag ID is received. It will continuously block the website if it has been blocked once already. Any explanation or help with this?

**JS file:**

```
var tag3 = '"*://www.twitter.com/*", "*://www.facebook.com/*"'

var tag2 = '"*://www.google.com/*", "*://www.imgur.com/*"'

var tag1 = '"*://www.yahoo.com/*"'

var tagger = "*://www.paint.com/*";

     chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
        function(details) { 
        return {cancel: true};
                    console.log(details.url);
         },
        {urls: [tagger]},
        ["blocking"]);








        // Set your API key first  

// Get feed content  
 xively.setKey( "CnfVSc8FlPqgma61r2Ym0B2VipqyiXbK7vJV67rijBo1Llwf" );
 console.log("XIVELY LOADED");

   var feedID        = 832936337,          // Feed ID  
      datastreamID  = "Reading";       // Datastream ID  
      data = "null";  // Your element on the page
      dataUpdated= "null";  


     console.log("READ ");


    xively.datastream.get (feedID, datastreamID, function ( datastream ) {  

    data = datastream["current_value"];
    console.log(data); 

    xively.datastream.subscribe( feedID, datastreamID, function ( event , datastream_updated ) {  

    dataUpdated = datastream_updated["current_value"] ;  
    console.log(dataUpdated);

    if (dataUpdated == "tag3") { 

    tagger = tag3;
    console.log(tagger);

    }
    else if (dataUpdated == "tag2") { 

    tagger = tag2;
    console.log(tagger);

    }
    if (dataUpdated == "tag1") { 

    tagger = tag1;
    console.log(tagger);

    }
    });  

  });  

        chrome.tabs.query({'active': true, 'windowId': chrome.windows.WINDOW_ID_CURRENT},
   function(tabs){
      console.log(tabs[0].url);
      if (tabs[0].url == "*www.twitter.com*") {
          alert("Twitter");
      }

   }
);
```

**Manifest File:**

```
   {
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "SiteBlockerFyp",
  "description": "Block Respective Sites",
  "version": "1",

"permissions": [
    "cookies",
    "<all_urls>",
    "history",
    "webRequest",
    "webRequestBlocking",
    "*://www.twitter.com/*","*://www.facebook.com/*","*://www.google.com/*","*://www.imgur.com/*","*://www.yahoo.com/*",
    "tabs"


  ],



"background": 
    {


      "scripts": ["jquery.min.js", "xivelyjs.min.js", "background.js"]


    }



}
```

Comment: Cleaning up your code would make it a lot easier for anyone who may be able to help you.

Comment: Cleaning up my code how? I can't do anything with a generic comment like "clean up your code" How?